# Encrypting a small part of the file instead of the whole file

Tags: encryption, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

I'm just getting into cryptography. I can encrypt my personal files with asymmetric encryption algorithms (using a script I wrote). But the problem is that I encrypt all the data of a file. That is, I extract the information of a 10GB file (bits) and then encrypt them using the encryption key.

Is there a safe way to encrypt only a small part of the file and the bits of the file instead of encrypting the whole 10GB file? By using this method, the encryption speed per file will increase, but I didn't find any specific idea on the internet.

My general quest is to spend less time on the whole operation when encrypting large amounts of data with asymmetric keys.
And my general idea is that instead of encrypting the entire data and bits of a file, only a small part or certain parts of the file are encrypted, and at the same time the file is still secure. If you have any ideas or sources about this, I would be grateful if you could guide me.

Comment: In real life, nobody encrypts data with asymmetric algorithms. They generate a new symmetric key, encrypt the data using e.g. AES, and then encrypt the symmetric key with a public key (see [Hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)).

Comment: thanks a lot. I read the article and got a deep understanding of how to encrypt with keys. My main question is still standing, so if anyone has any ideas about it, I would be grateful if you could give me more guidance or link to educational articles.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to encrypt a piece of a file in-place? That would need extra tricks, since encrypted data is larger than plain. It includes initialization vector and padding which also needs to be stored somewhere, so you'll need to invent a custom format, comparing to calling `openssl` to encrypt the entire file. If your concern is performance, AES is [_very_ fast](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/44934/8323), you can try it with your file and see if that's fast enough for you before diving deeper.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that for many files encrypting only a small part provides little security benefit since so much is unencrypted. If you have a file full of sensitive data then you need to encrypt all of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. My general idea is that: in normal encryption, we encrypt all the information and bits of a 50GB file, in the end that file is encrypted and safe. But is it necessary to encrypt a 50GB data? all its bits and file data should be completely encrypted? Is it possible to encrypt this file, instead of encrypting 50 GB bits, only a smaller part (for example, the first 512 bytes of the file) can be encrypted? And the file has the same security !

Comment: What do you mean `the file has the same security`? Encryption has certain features and guarantees - the output looks random and there is no way to extract any extra information. If only small part is encrypted, then the rest stays plain. Symmetric encr (with AES hardware support) it's often faster than device I/O, so overall performance difference is very small